# prove that $an(n+1)+2n\ge4 \sqrt a(\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt n)$

Tags: inequality

It is given that $a \in  \mathbf R^+$ and $n \in \mathbf Z$

prove that 
$$an(n+1)+2n\ge4 \sqrt a(\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt n)$$

No idea about how to solve this one.please help. A full answer with a nice explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like the LHS is two cases, one where $a>1$ and one where $a\leq 1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry sir but i did not get it

Comment: Do you know about Riemman integrals? Because the part ibn the parens on the right hand side sure looks like an approximation of $\int_0^n \sqrt{x} ~ dx$ (indeed, it's just slightly larger than that value, which can be computed via an integral pretty easily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a>0$, ... from AM-GM, $\frac12\left(ak + 1\right)\geq\sqrt{ak}$, and summing over $k$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac12 (ak+1)\right)\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{ak}\right)$$
$$\frac{a}{2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right) + \frac{n}2 \geq  \sqrt{a}\left(1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt n \right)$$
$$an(n+1) + 2n \geq 4\sqrt a\left(1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt n \right)$$
As desired.

Comment: can u plz explain how did u get first part of second equation plz sir.($\frac{a}{2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right) + \frac{n}2=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac12 (ak+1)\right)$)

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA, you can break the sum into parts, and use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n k= \frac12 n(n+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$an(n+1)-4\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+...+\sqrt {n})+2n=2\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{ak}-1)^2$$
It will be sufficient to show that $(\sqrt{ak}-1)^2\ge 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, which is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Induction, for $n + 1$:
$$
a(n+1)(n+2)+2n + 2\ge4 \sqrt a(\sqrt1+\sqrt2+...+\sqrt n+\sqrt {n + 1})
$$
Assuming true for $n$:
$$
2a(n+1) + 2 \ge 4\sqrt a \sqrt {n + 1}
$$
equivalent
$$
(\sqrt a  \sqrt {n+1} - 1)^2 \ge  0
$$

Comment: i didnt get ur second step sir.can u plz explain

Comment: $a(n+1)(n+2)+2n + 2=an(n+1) + 2a(n+1) + 2n + 2$ and I assume $an(n+1)+2n\ge4 \sqrt a(\sqrt1+\sqrt2+...+\sqrt n)$ so the remaining to prove is the second inegality

Comment: how is $a(n+1) + 1-2\sqrt a \sqrt {n + 1}=(\sqrt a - \sqrt {n+1})^2$??

Comment: @Axel Blaze Actually $(\sqrt a  \sqrt {n+1} - 1)^2 \ge  0$, I make a mistake.